# Ndk Error in Android Studio When Building apk

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I got this error when I clicked build apk in Android Studio.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Users\Webspace\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1

Can't find a solution for this. I am a newbie in android development. Can anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a clean project. If it does not work, try restarting the Android Studio.

If these steps do not work, try changing the "buildToolsVersion" in build.gradle file to "23.0.2" or higher.

You can try also to add this, in your build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

PS. Ensure that the path to your NDK is correct in "local.properties" folder!